# Can't load image on my webhost

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

Hi guys I'm having a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` while loading my image from my `file manager` on my webhost and it's always printing `.showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)`

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [carkila.esy.es/upload/20160808114541.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [carkila.esy.es/upload/20160808114541.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And here is my UILConfig.java

```
public class UILConfig {
public static ImageLoaderConfiguration config (Context context){

    final DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) //filled width
            .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {
                    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,200,200,false);
                }
            })
            .build();

    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) // default
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir)) // default
            .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .diskCacheFileCount(100)
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .build();
    return config;
}
}
```

How I load the image.

```
        dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `carkila.esy.es/upload/20160808114541.png` doesn't contain a scheme. Try `http://carkila.esy.es/upload/20160808114541.png`